# About the combination of OpenMP and -Ofast

Tags: c, optimization, openmp

I implemented **OpenMP parallelization in a for loop** where I have a **sum** that is the principal cause of slowing down my code. When I did so, I found out that the final results were not the same that I obtained for the non-parallelize code (which is written in C). So first, one might think "well, I just didn't implemented well the parallelization" but the curious thing is that when I run the parallelized code with the **-Ofast** optimization suddenly the results are correct.

That would be:

- -O0 correct
- -Ofast correct
- OMP -O0 wrong
- OMP -O1 wrong
- OMP -O2 wrong
- OMP -O3 wrong
- OMP -Ofast correct!

What could -Ofast be doing that solves an error that only appears when I implement openmp? 
Any recommendation of what could I check or test?
Thanks!

**EDIT**
Here I include the smallest version of my code that still reproduces the problem.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>

#define LENGTH 100
#define R 50.0
#define URD 1.0/sqrt(2.0)
#define PI (4.0*atan(1.0)) //pi

const gsl_rng_type * Type;
gsl_rng * item;

double CalcDeltaEnergy(double **M,int sx,int sy){
    double DEnergy,r,zz;
    int k,j;
    double rrx,rry;
    int rx,ry;
    double Energy, Cpm, Cmm, Cmp, Cpp;
    DEnergy = 0;

    //OpenMP parallelization:
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:DEnergy)
    for (int index = 0; index < LENGTH*LENGTH; index++){
        k = index % LENGTH;
        j = index / LENGTH;

    zz = 0.5*(1.0 - pow(-1.0, k + j + sx + sy));
    for (rx = -1; rx <= 1; rx++){
        for (ry = -1; ry <= 1; ry++){
            rrx = (sx - k - rx*LENGTH)*URD;
            rry = (sy - j - ry*LENGTH)*URD;

            r = sqrt(rrx*rrx + rry*rry + zz);
            if(r != 0 && r <= R){
                Cpm = sqrt((rrx+0.5*(0.702*cos(M[k][j])-0.702*cos(M[sx][sy])))*(rrx+0.5*(0.702*cos(M[k][j])-0.702*cos(M[sx][sy]))) + (rry+0.5*(0.702*sin(M[k][j])-0.702*sin(M[sx][sy])))*(rry+0.5*(0.702*sin(M[k][j])-0.702*sin(M[sx][sy]))) + zz);
                Cmm = sqrt((rrx-0.5*(0.702*cos(M[k][j])-0.702*cos(M[sx][sy])))*(rrx-0.5*(0.702*cos(M[k][j])-0.702*cos(M[sx][sy]))) + (rry-0.5*(0.702*sin(M[k][j])-0.702*sin(M[sx][sy])))*(rry-0.5*(0.702*sin(M[k][j])-0.702*sin(M[sx][sy]))) + zz);
                Cpp = sqrt((rrx+0.5*(0.702*cos(M[k][j])+0.702*cos(M[sx][sy])))*(rrx+0.5*(0.702*cos(M[k][j])+0.702*cos(M[sx][sy]))) + (rry+0.5*(0.702*sin(M[k][j])+0.702*sin(M[sx][sy])))*(rry+0.5*(0.702*sin(M[k][j])+0.702*sin(M[sx][sy]))) + zz);
                Cmp = sqrt((rrx-0.5*(0.702*cos(M[k][j])+0.702*cos(M[sx][sy])))*(rrx-0.5*(0.702*cos(M[k][j])+0.702*cos(M[sx][sy]))) + (rry-0.5*(0.702*sin(M[k][j])+0.702*sin(M[sx][sy])))*(rry-0.5*(0.702*sin(M[k][j])+0.702*sin(M[sx][sy]))) + zz);
                Cpm = 1.0/Cpm;
                Cmm = 1.0/Cmm;
                Cpp = 1.0/Cpp;
                Cmp = 1.0/Cmp;
                Energy = (Cpm + Cmm - Cpp - Cmp)/(0.702*0.702); // S=cte=1

                DEnergy -= 2.0*Energy;
            }
        }
    }
    }
return DEnergy;
}

void Initialize(double **M){
double random;
    for(int i=0;i<(LENGTH-1);i=i+2){
          for(int j=0;j<(LENGTH-1);j=j+2) {
              random=gsl_rng_uniform(item);
              if (random<0.5) M[i][j]=PI/4.0;
              else M[i][j]=5.0*PI/4.0;

              random=gsl_rng_uniform(item);
              if (random<0.5) M[i][j+1]=3.0*PI/4.0;
              else M[i][j+1]=7.0*PI/4.0;

              random=gsl_rng_uniform(item);
              if (random<0.5) M[i+1][j]=3.0*PI/4.0;
              else M[i+1][j]=7.0*PI/4.0;

              random=gsl_rng_uniform(item);
              if (random<0.5) M[i+1][j+1]=PI/4.0;
              else M[i+1][j+1]=5.0*PI/4.0;
          }
    }
}

int main(){
    //Choose and initiaze the random number generator
    gsl_rng_env_setup();
    Type = gsl_rng_default; //default=mt19937, ran2, lxs0
    item = gsl_rng_alloc (Type);

    double **S; //site matrix
    S = (double **) malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        S[i] = (double *) malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(double ));

    //Initialization
    Initialize(S);

    int l,m;
    for (int cl = 0; cl < LENGTH*LENGTH; cl++) {
        l = gsl_rng_uniform_int(item, LENGTH); // RNG[0, LENGTH-1]
        m = gsl_rng_uniform_int(item, LENGTH); // RNG[0, LENGTH-1]
        printf("%lf\n", CalcDeltaEnergy(S, l, m));
    }


    //Free memory
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        free(S[i]);
    free(S);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with:

```
g++ [optimization] -lm test.c -o test.x -lgsl -lgslcblas -fopenmp
```

and run with:

```
GSL_RNG_SEED=123; ./test.x > test.dat
```

Comparing the outputs for different optimizations one can see what I stated before.

Comment: It'll be practical to see an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It may just be undefined behaviour you're running into, such as not initializing a starting variable.

Comment: If you use a compiler for which -Ofast implies simd reduction, each of your reduction methods with varying orders of summation would imply small (insignificant) differences.

Comment: @Evert, there I added the reduced example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have little to no experience with OpenMP

### It's probably a race condition you run into when using OpenMP.

You'll need to declare all those variables inside the OpenMP loop to be *private*. One core may calculate their values for a certain value of `index`, which gets promptly recalculated to different values on a core that uses another value of `index`: the variables such as `k`, `j`, `rrx`, `rry` etc are shared between the compute nodes.

Instead of using a pragma like

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(k,j,zz,rx,ry,rrx,rry,r,Cpm,Cmm,Cpp,Cmp,Energy) reduction (+:D\
```

(credits to comment by Zulan below:) you can also declare the variables inside the parallel region, as locally as possible. This makes them private implicitly and is less prone to initialization issues and easier to reason about.

(You could even consider putting everything inside the outer for-loop (over `index`) in a function: the function call overhead is minimal compared to the calculations.)

### As to why `-Ofast` together with OpenMP does actually produce correct output.

My guess is: mostly luck. Here's what `-Ofast` does (gcc manual):

> Disregard strict standards compliance.  -Ofast enables all -O3 optimizations.  It also enables optimizations that are not valid for all standard-compliant programs. It turns on -ffast-math [...]

Here's the section on `-ffast-math`:

> This option is not turned on by any -O option besides -Ofast since it can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions. It may, however, yield faster code for programs that do not require the guarantees of these specifications.

Thus, the `sqrt`, `cos` and `sin` will likely be a lot speedier. My guess is, that in this case, the calculations of the variables inside the outer loop don't bite each other, since the individual threads are so fast, they don't conflict. But that is a very handwavingly explanation and guess.

Comment: Note that instead of explicitly declaring the variables private in the `pragma`, or making a new function, you can also declare the variables inside the parallel region, as locally as possible. This makes them private implicitly and is less prone to initialization issues and easier to reason about.

Comment: @Zulan Thanks; edited in. With C99 style variable declaration, this is easy (I may have never even run into this hurdle, since that is standard style for me nowadays). That also explains that a function call will work, since all those variables are declared inside the function, which is called inside the OpenMP loop.

Comment: Your suggestion of making all the inner variables as local as possible solves the problem. The question of why Ofast leads to the correct answer remains unclear to me, but your guess has a lot of sense and it should be proved. Thank you very much for all your comments and the help!